# Firebase Functions, upgrading node 16 to node 18 breaks ffmpeg: fails to launch with ENOENT

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This works in Firebase Functions when `"engines": { "node": "16" }` is set (we use it in production now).

package.json dep: `"@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0"`

code:

```
      await spawn(
        'ffmpeg',
        [...],
      );
```

When I upgrade Node to 18, it fails with `spawn ffmpeg ENOENT`

Anyone know the incantation that works for node 18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't been using the `ffmpeg-installer` package but it could be related to the fact that the Cloud Function execution environment for Node 16 uses Ubuntu 18.04 as OS, while Node 18 and Node 20 use Ubuntu 22.04 (see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment).

And Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't come with `ffmpeg` as a system package anymore (see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages).

It was also discussed here, with the conclusion "nope, ffmpeg not gonna happen": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242685280

I'm currently running into the same issue, my 2 cents on this:

1. So far my solution was to stay on Node 16, but I'm being presented kind reminders that Node 16 will be deprecated from Jan 2024 on in Cloud Functions.
2. So next option is to download (https://ffbinaries.com/downloads) and include the ffmpeg binary file (or files, if also using ffprobe) in your functions directory, e.g. at root level in `/functions/ffmpeg-bin` and set the PATH variable somewhere in your functions through something like this (specify relative path from calling function to binaries directory):

   ```
   process.env.PATH = `${process.env.PATH}:${path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "ffmpeg-bin")}`;
   ```

   The downside here is that you now always deploy like 90MB more, which is annoying.
3. Also possible to upload the binaries to Cloud Storage, and download them into function memory on `/tmp/` at every execution. But also doesn't feel like the most elegant solution. For example by:

   ```
   import { exec } from "child_process";
   import { promisify } from "util";
   import fs from "fs";

   const ffmpegPath = "/tmp/ffmpeg";
   const ffprobePath = "/tmp/ffprobe";
   const execPromise = promisify(exec);

   // Check if the ffmpeg binary already exists in the /tmp directory
   if (!fs.existsSync(ffmpegPath)) {
       // Download ffmpeg binary from Cloud Storage
       const bucket = storage.bucket("your-bucket-id");
       const fileFfmpeg = bucket.file("path-to-ffmpeg");
       const fileFfprobe = bucket.file("path-to-ffprobe");

       const promises = [
         fileFfmpeg.download({ destination: ffmpegPath }),
         fileFfprobe.download({ destination: ffprobePath }),
       ];
       await Promise.all(promises);

       // Make the binary executable
       await execPromise(`chmod +x ${ffmpegPath}`);
       await execPromise(`chmod +x ${ffprobePath}`);
   }
   ```

   and then use by running

   ```
   await execPromise(`${ffmpegPath} -i  input.mp4 -your-options output.mp4`)
   ```
4. Doing more advanced stuff with Artifact Registry or Cloud Run.

Would also be happy to hear if there are better ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Oof on the google engineer being "nope too bad". But many thanks for the writeup & suggestions! Will look into these.

Comment: Sure! Actually did some more testing, and for me it works better to upload the `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` binaries to Cloud Storage and download them into function memory on execution. Downloading from Cloud Storage to a Cloud Function is pretty fast (~5 sec), while adding those MB in deployment took ages for me. BUT depends on the individual situation. When you deploy less often but functions are called very often it probably makes more sense to include the binaries with the deployment package...

Comment: Hmm, yeah, this isn't deployed often but it is called thousands of times an hour. Mind you with Firebase Functions v2, don't these keep running for a while and accept multiple incoming connections? (This is an https callable function in my case) ... so perhaps downloading the binary would still work

Comment: I ended up bundling the binary in my functions source because it's only about 27MB zipped, and we don't deploy this function much. Going to go to production with this and see how it goes...